# Specify a background image that works both in the parent and in the child page

Tags: asp.net, directory, filenames

I am using a background image for a module. If I write

```
background = "DesktopModules/DNAiusParallelSlider/Images/waves.gif";
```

it works fine in the parent page, but it does not work in the child page. If I write

```
background = "../DesktopModules/DNAiusParallelSlider/Images/waves.gif";
```

it works in the child page but not in the parent.

How can I specify a background that works at all levels?

Answer (score 1):

try "~" like:

```
 backgrd = "~/DesktopModules/DNAiusParallelSlider/Images/waves.gif";
```

Comment: it worked i used Page.ResolveUrl("../DesktopModules/DNAiusParallelSlider/Images/waves.gif";) –

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative URLs. Which means they are **relative** to the current directory of your page.

Use an **absolute** URL:

```
/DesktopModules/DNAiusParallelSlider/Images/waves.gif
```

Read more about absolute and relative URLs here:

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3

Comment: it worked i used Page.ResolveUrl("../DesktopModules/DNAiusParallelSlider/Images/waves.gif";)